# Prevent input being updated from ng-model whilst editing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding

My `model.field` can be modified by the user typing into an input element but also by some other function in the background. When the user is typing a change into the input I want to ignore any changes to the model made by those background functions. Eg:

```
$scope.model = {
    field: 'val1'
}
```

html

```
<input ng-model="model.field" ...>
```

IE:

- The model.field has value 'val1'
- The user starts editing the input (it is active)
- The model changes by some other means to 'val2'
- The new value is not shown in the input - it still shows 'val1'
- The next key stroke the user makes (changes 1 to A) overwrites whatever is in the model.field.
- The model.field now has value 'valA'

Comment: What is changing the value? If it's something local then you could set a local flag to `true` using `ng-change` as the trigger and to `false` using `ng-blur` as the trigger. Check the status of this flag before updating the field. If it's something remote (two users editing the same record?) then you'd have to implement some type of record locking logic in your server or database (or whatever).

Comment: I agree on the approach suggested by Lex, you could also hack around the ngForm API to check if the user is actively editing or not. Here a very hacky example http://plnkr.co/edit/lFbcmjCUcvn68nRPbkPf?p=preview

Comment: I'm looking into extending `ng-model` to turn off the 2-way binding until the `ng-blur` event fires: https://github.com/Plippe/extends-ng-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a $formatter which ignores the model when the element has focus seems to work well:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('ngModelIgnoreWhenActive', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModelCtrl) {

            //Track if the element has focus. 
            //True when the user is typing into the field; false otherwise
            scope.hasFocus = false; 
            element.on('focus', function(event) {
                scope.hasFocus = true;
            });
            element.on('blur', function(event) {
                scope.hasFocus = false;
            });

            //Formats value before shown in view
            // If the element has focus, keep it's existing value
            var myFormatter = function(newValue) {
                return scope.hasFocus && element && element[0] ? element[0].value : newValue;
            }

            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(myFormatter);
        }
    };
});
```

You then add the directive to any relevant input:

```
<input ng-model="model.field" ng-model-ignore-when-active>
```

Based the code on the extends-ng-model timestamp formatter shown here: https://github.com/Plippe/extends-ng-model/blob/master/src/extends-ng-model/ng-model-formatter-parser/ng-model-timestamp.js